# Scala Future flatMap implementation (chaining)

Tags: scala

Trying to wrap my head around how async tasks are chained together, for ex futures and `flatMap`

```
val a: Future[Int] = Future { 123 }
val b: Future[Int] = a.flatMap(a => Future { a + 321 })
```

How would i implement something similar where i build a new `Future` by waiting for `a` first and applying a `f` on the result. I tried looking a scala's source code but got stuck here: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/Future.scala#L216

i would imagine some code like:

```
def myFlatMap(a: Future[Int])(f: a => Future[Int]): Future[Int] = {
   Future {
      // somehow wait for a to complete and the apply 'f'
      a.onComplete {
        case Success(x) => f(a)
      }
   }
}
```

but i guess above will return a Future[Unit] instead. I would just like to understand the "pattern" of how async tasks are chained together.

Comment: Sorry, I did not get, do you want to implement map? I'm wondering, because what you saying sounds similar to simple map.

Comment: its the same with map, i just trying to understand how map / flatMap could be implemented on a async container like Future under the hood.

Comment: Basically using a `Promise` or a callback, you create a new future that "waits" _(in a semantic sense, not in a real blocking sense)_ for the first future to completes and then executes the function. And you return a future that represents that new value.

Comment: Yeah thats the difficult part to wrap my head around, would you be able to create an example implementation of what Future.flatMap does under the hood?

Comment: Remember that a `Future` is basically a better, more powerful and easier to use, callback. As such you can think of it as a function that will be executed when another function finishes and triggers the callback.  `map` is just applying a function to that result before calling the next callback, `flatMap` is basically adding a callback to this callback. - Is not really easy to explain in text, look for a talk called _"How do fibres work under the hood"_ by Fabio Labella, `Futures` are a special kind of Fiber, so even if the talk is aimed to **cats-effect** `Fibers`, the content is very general

Comment: Im not looking for solutions to a problem, im trying to understand how `flatMap` in general works for tasks that needs to be "awaited" on `Future` is just an example, but it could just as well be Timer[IO].sleep(123) etc. Speaking of `cats` i tried to look into the Monad / FlatMap impl of Future but they simply forward to the underlaying Future.flatMap, so still not sure what is going on under the hood there, maybe you can point me to the actual impl?

Comment: Very simple. You never await. You have a container with a function and mutable-and-hard-to-get-right list of observers. You post that on Thread Pool which runs some `Runnable` which synchronously calls function and then propagate the result to observers. Since observers are other `Future`s they would upon receiving the result schedule their functions and observers to Thread Pool and so on.

Comment: And if you are still wondering how all of that translates to `flatMap` you can just open the source code of `Future` or any other IO monad. It's public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I'm the main maintainer of Scala Futures)

You wouldn't want to implement flatMap/recoverWith/transformWith yourself—it is a very complex feature to implement safely (stack-safe, memory-safe, and concurrency-safe).

You can see what I am talking about here:

- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L442
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L307
- https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/concurrent/impl/Promise.scala#L274

There is more reading on the topic here: https://viktorklang.com/blog/Futures-in-Scala-2.12-part-9.html

Comment: Thanks, it was not so much that i wanted to implement Future or similar my self, it was only to help better understand how async tasks "wait" under the hood when flatMap etc. maybe my question was unclear, but your answer helped me in the right direction thanks!

Comment: At it's very core it is about a race condition between completing a Promise and adding a callback. Of course it gets much more complicated than that when one wants performance, reliability, safety, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found that looking at the source for scala `2.12` was easier for me to understand how `Future` / `Promise` was implemented, i learned that `Future` is in fact a `Promise` and by looking at the implementation i now understand how "chaining" async tasks can be implemented.

Im posting the code that i wrote to help me better understand what was going on under the hood.

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.{ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, TimeUnit}
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

trait MyAsyncTask[T] {
  type Callback = T => Unit
  var result: Option[T]

  // register a new callback to be called when task is completed.
  def onComplete(callback: Callback): Unit
  // complete the given task, and invoke all registered callbacks.
  def complete(value: T): Unit

  // create a new task, that will wait for the current task to complete and apply
  // the provided map function, and complete the new task when completed.
  def flatMap[B](f: T => MyAsyncTask[B]): MyAsyncTask[B] = {
    val wrapper = new DefaultAsyncTask[B]()
    onComplete { x =>
      f(x).onComplete { y =>
        wrapper.complete(y)
      }
    }

    wrapper
  }

  def map[B](f: T => B): MyAsyncTask[B] = flatMap(x => CompletedAsyncTask(f(x)))
}

/**
  * task with fixed pre-calculated result.
  */
case class CompletedAsyncTask[T](value: T) extends MyAsyncTask[T] {
  override var result: Option[T] = Some(value)
  override def onComplete(callback: Callback): Unit = {
    // we already have the result just call the callback.
    callback(value)
  }

  override def complete(value: T): Unit = () // noop nothing to complete.
}

class DefaultAsyncTask[T] extends MyAsyncTask[T] {
  override var result: Option[T] = None
  var isCompleted = false
  var listeners = new ListBuffer[Callback]()

  /**
    * register callback, to be called when task is completed.
    */
  override def onComplete(callback: Callback): Unit = {
    if (isCompleted) {
      // already completed just invoke callback
      callback(result.get)
    } else {
      // add the listener
      listeners.addOne(callback)
    }
  }

  /**
    * trigger all registered callbacks to `onComplete`
    */
  override def complete(value: T): Unit = {
    result = Some(value)
    listeners.foreach { listener =>
      listener(value)
    }
  }
}

object MyAsyncTask {
  def apply[T](body: (T => Unit) => Unit): MyAsyncTask[T] = {
    val task = new DefaultAsyncTask[T]()
    // pass in `complete` as callback.
    body(task.complete)

    task
  }
}

object MyAsyncFlatMap {

  /**
    * helper to simulate async task.
    */
  def delayedCall(body: => Unit, delay: Int): Unit = {
    val scheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1)
    val run = new Runnable {
      override def run(): Unit = {
        body
      }
    }

    scheduler.schedule(run, delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val getAge = MyAsyncTask[Int] { cb =>
      delayedCall({ cb(66) }, 1)
    }

    val getName = MyAsyncTask[String] { cb =>
      delayedCall({ cb("John") }, 2)
    }

    // same as: getAge.flatMap(age => getName.map(name => (age, name)))
    val result: MyAsyncTask[(Int, String)] = for {
      age <- getAge
      name <- getName
    } yield (age, name)

    result.onComplete {
      case (age, name) => println(s"hello $name $age")
    }
  }
}
```